# Getting error in pasting values after last used row from one worksheet to another in vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Y").Range("A:L").Copy
Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Z").Activate
last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(last_row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

In the above code, I am getting "**Runtime error 1004 Copy and paste area are not the same size, you can't paste here**". Kindly help me with an updated version of the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to Paste all (including the empty ones) into a Column several rows down.  There is just not enough room.  An easy way around this is to use the Intersect Method to trim all the Cells not in the UsedRange of the Worksheet.

```
Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
With Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Y")
    Set Source = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A:L"))
End With

If Not Source Is Nothing Then
    With Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Z")
        Set Target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Source.Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End If
```

Because you are only interested in the data and not the formatting, I would copy the Source range values into an Array and then write the array to the Target Range.

```
Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
Dim Data As Variant
With Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Y")
    Set Source = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A:L"))
End With

If Not Source Is Nothing Then
    Data = Source.Value
    With Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Z")
        Set Target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Target.Resize(UBound(Data), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End With
End If
```

[Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) will demonstrate why you should not Activate or Select Ranges, Workbooks, Worksheets...etc.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas, I have tried this code, This code is not giving any error but It paste the record in the same worksheet that is worksheet("Y") but I want the records to be pasted in the worksheet("Z") after last used row, what should I do?

Comment: I don't see how that is possible.